# How do I fill out a matrix with dots?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, matrices

I want to illustrate the use of dots in LaTeX.

Here is the output I am looking for:

[image]

This is the code I am starting with:

```
   $$
  L= \left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 \quad\cdots\quad0\\
  m_{2,1} & 1 & 0 \quad\cdots\quad0\\
  m_{3,1} & m_{3,2} & 1 \quad\cdots\quad0\\
   \\
  \end{array}  
   \right]
  $$
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: your title asks about `\dots`  (a command defined by `amsmath`) but your example code and accepted answer demonstrates `\cdots` do you want to change the title?

Comment: yes please change my title.

Comment: @constantinosgeorgiou: You can edit your title by selecting the "edit" button at the bottom left of the question.  Since you posted it, you should have edit privileges on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

With use of the `amsmath` package (for `bmatrix`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
L=  \begin{bmatrix}
    1   &   0       & 0         & \cdots    & 0\\
m_{2,1} &   1       & 0         & \cdots    & 0\\
m_{3,1} & m_{3,2}   & 1         & \cdots    & 0\\
\vdots  & \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots    & \vdots\\
m_{n,1} & m_{n,2}   & \cdots    & m_{n,n-1} & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```